# AWS CLI cloudwatch log subscription without any filter pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to get logs from an application running in AWS, including all logs without any filter pattern:

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter --log-group-name "abc-loggroup" --filter-name "Destination" --filter-pattern "" --destination-arn "arn:test" --role-arn "arn:role"
```

getting following error -
aws: error: argument --filter-pattern: expected one argument

Tried running the command without "--filter-name" parameter it failed.

How can I run this command without any filter pattern

Comment: probably a bit late but you should try with last version of awscli v2 : `aws --version`:  `aws-cli/2.4.19 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.10.0-11-amd64 exe/x86_64.debian.11 prompt/off` I just tested it and in aws console I can see `Filter pattern: None`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [PutSubscriptionFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutSubscriptionFilter.html#CWL-PutSubscriptionFilter-request-filterPattern), you need to provide both params.

`filterPattern`

> A filter pattern for subscribing to a filtered stream of log events.

> Type: String

> Length Constraints: Minimum length of 0. Maximum length of 1024.

> Required: Yes

`filterName`

> Type: String

> Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 512.

> Pattern: [^:*]*

> Required: Yes